# Powerpoint Slide Master Different Fonts

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I am a long time PowerPoint power user, however, I have run into a qwerk that I cannot seem to solve.

I was requested to build a template with multiple kernings for three different fonts in different sizes for title, subtitle, body, small body, etc. (Also different paragraph spacing for each).

I have the master slide that looks great, but when I make a slide from that layout it changes all the fonts to be the font from the "main" slide master body text.

Any idea how to circumvent this or work around it?

Comment: Have you verified the slide theme/master via *Home > Layout*.

Comment: Yep, everything looks like the master, but it changes the fonts, kerning, and paragraph settings from what the master has.

Comment: I think this must be a bug in PowerPoint. I wonder if you change the layout to another theme, then back to yours, if the fonts come back.